# nodetool cfstats on DSE restart

Tags: cassandra

On DSE restart, I can see that the Read and Write counts/latency values reset to zero.

Does the following values also get reset?

```
                Compression metadata off heap memory used: 1123544
                Compacted partition minimum bytes: 87
                Compacted partition maximum bytes: 129557750
                Compacted partition mean bytes: 48702
                Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 238.6153846153846
                Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 888.0
                Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
                Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
```

After DSE restart, I am seeing that the values changed from what it was showing earlier. How does cfstats work?

Comment: include version please

Comment: DSE 4.8.5, Cassandra 2.1.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom 4

```
            Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 238.6153846153846
            Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 888.0
            Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
            Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
```

are stats on number of cells and tombstones touched on reads. These will reset on restarts. But

```
            Compression metadata off heap memory used: 1123544
            Compacted partition minimum bytes: 87
            Compacted partition maximum bytes: 129557750
            Compacted partition mean bytes: 48702
```

Are stats on the sstables for the table, they are on disk and will not reset.